# Value of type '1-dimensional array of Integer' cannot be converted to 'UInteger'. VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, integer, uint32

Pretty simple code no idea why it doesn't work obviously UInteger aka UInt32 can hold double of what Integer can hold so it doesn't make sense why it doesn't fit, it's not even negative it's just hexadecimals.

```
Dim xor_table As UInt32 = {&H40FC1578, &H113B6C1F, &H8389CA19, _
&HE2196CD8, &H74901489, &H4AAB1566, &H7B8C12A0, &H18FFCD, &HCCAB704B, _
&H7B5A8C0F, &HAA13B891, &HDE419807, &H12FFBCAE, &H5F5FBA34, &H10F5AC99, _
&HB1C1DD01}
```

Comment: If it is just a typo then you can delete the question

Comment: yeah it was.. but then again someone might have this problem and this is the only result on google that will help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the constants with type characters.

```
    Dim xor_table() As UInt32 = {&H40FC1578, &H113B6C1F, &H8389CA19UI, &HE2196CD8UI, &H74901489, _
                                 &H4AAB1566, &H7B8C12A0, &H18FFCD, &HCCAB704BUI, &H7B5A8C0FUI, _
                                 &HAA13B891UI, &HDE419807UI, &H12FFBCAE, &H5F5FBA34, &H10F5AC99, _
                                 &HB1C1DD01UI}
```

Answer (score 1):

forgot the array `()` symbols sorry guys!

must be

```
Dim xor_table() As UInt32
```